# What is a term for a phenomenon where two people doing the same job are less effective than one person doing it alone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

For example, imagine a worker in a widget factory who is responsible for checking if all the widgets on a conveyor belt are well-made. This worker is successful in their job 99% of the time. However, when a second worker is added to the same task, and both workers are aware of the other, the accuracy rate drops to 90% because both workers assume that the *other* person will do a good job.

Is there a word or phrase to describe this phenomenon? It's related to "bystander effect" but not exactly it.

Comment: Soomething you might want to look into: Diseconomies of scale. Describes the phenomenon that from a certain point onward, an addition of productive resources to an economic undertaking does not add but rather removes utility.

Comment: There is the law of diminishing returns, but this is somewhat different.

Comment: Seeing that the answers are split between idiomatic expressions and economic / business jargon, you might want to specify what type of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Sounds like a case of 'too many cooks'.  That is a shortening of the proverb that is clearly recognised in the abbreviation not mentioning the spoiled broth.

Comment: Erm... ***normal**?* Job-sharing might suit some *workers*, but it's almost always gonna be more expensive / less efficient from the empoyer's perspective.

Answer (score 39):

Since you mention the "bystander effect", I guess you're looking for a psychological term. This would be "[**Diffusion of responsibility**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility)", even though its prime examples are mostly taken from emergency situations:

> The diffusion of responsibility refers to the decreased responsibility of action each member of a group feels when they are part of a group. For example, in emergency situations, individuals feel less responsibility to respond or call for help if they know that there are others also watching the situation - if they know they are a part of the group of witnesses

Further down the article, both "bystander effect" and "social loafing" (as [mentioned by JonathanReez](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601155)) are listed as two possible consequences of diffusion of responsibility.

Comment: This seems like the best fit for OP's question.

Comment: What do you call it when this diffusion of responsibility is intentional and used as an excuse to let someone die? Good examples are (1) [The rainmaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rainmaker_(novel)), a novel by John Grisham adapted into a film with Matt Damon, and (2) two awful true stories from 2021 and 2022 about British and French coast guards refusing to rescue drowning migrants despite the repeated radio calls for help.

Comment: @Stef A "lame excuse", punishable due to "failure to assist a person in danger".

Answer (score 25):

This sounds like a case in which **too many cooks spoil the soup.**

[This means, according to The Free Dictionary:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+cooks+spoil+the+soup)

> If too many people try to control, influence, or work on something, the final product will be worse as a result.

Comment: I have always heard this as "too many cooks spoil the **broth**". Google ngram suggests it has been the more common expression since at least 1800.

Comment: This idiom is used when people show overinvolvement in an activity/task(thus botching up the whole thing), rather than tacitly assuming the other person to carry it out.

Comment: @Peter It's interesting. Looking it up, I found the same thing. But I've heard the "soup" version a lot more often. Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: I've only ever heard 'broth' - but cunningly countered by 'many hands make light work'. UK, maybe?

Comment: @Peter We would just say "too many cooks in the kitchen". (Although it's different from the example the OP gives, since none of the "cooks" are presumed to be slacking...just that they are getting in each others way.)

Comment: There's a popular Adult Swim video called "Too Many Cooks" that supports the claim that this is a well-established idiom. It also suggests that "broth" is the more popular completion. I'm not linking it because it's got some mild nudity and quite a lot of violence (including cannibalism), but it's easy to find online. It's also pretty funny.

Comment: This proverb means everyone is trying, and everyone's trying amounts to too much. It has nothing to do with workers assuming “that the other person will do a good job.”

Comment: I usually just hear "too many cooks", or "too many chiefs"

Answer (score 23):

There is a term in software development called [Brooks's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27s_law). The idea is that adding additional personnel to a project will increase, not decrease the time it takes to complete it.

The idea is typically that the overhead of adding more people to the task is more work for the people already engaged in the task, increases the burden of communication as you don't want to make changes that impact other's work, and that knowledge of the entire system is necessary to begin working and thus the task is largely non-divisible anyway.

I've never heard it referenced outside of software development but unlike other answers doesn't come with the implication that the people involved are just doing sloppier work, its just a feature of the task.

Comment: I understood the question as asking about the name of an effect that precisely involves people doing sloppier work because they know that they are not the only responsible person. Still, this answer has value in case I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Well, the questioner said it was "related to bystander effect" but not exactly it. Your answer is closer to a synonym whereas mine is related but distinct. I think both have value but no one had taken my angle yet.

Comment: Well, yes, "bystander effect" describes "people not _re_acting because they're in a group", while the question asks for "people not acting to their full potential because they're in a group". In the first case, they're not yet involved (as "bystander" suggests); in the latter, they are already involved. I think that was the motivation to mention the "bystander effect".

Comment: Related: "The Mythical Man-Month: Essays on Software Engineering". Specifically the term "Mythical Man-Month".

Comment: Brooks uses the analogy of putting more women on the job to have a baby in 3 months. And that shows how "job" has many meanings, not all of which are countable.

Comment: You misspelled "Brooks' law".  It's Fred Brooks, not Fred Brook.

Comment: Oof, so it is. Thanks - I edited in the correction.

Answer (score 19):

I think the right term is **social loafing**, [which Wiki defines as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_loafing):

> Social loafing is the phenomenon of a person exerting less effort to
> achieve a goal when they work in a group than when working
> alone. It is seen as one of the main reasons groups are
> sometimes less productive than the combined performance of their
> members working as individuals.

Comment: +1. I learned something new today! But for it being jargon (which might be okay for the OP's purposes), this is exact.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a specific aspect/manifestation of the "tragedy of the commons".

Comment: It's worth noting that "tragedy of the commons" was propaganda.

Comment: @CodyGray As I understand the "tragedy of the commons", it is when producers are incentivized to over-use a public resource because the results of their production are privately held.  Other than there being "too many" of something, I don't see how that applies at all to OP's posit.

Comment: The term is not nearly that specific, @Kirt. It generally refers to the phenomenon where people who have unfettered access to a resource tend to act independently according to their own self-interest and, thus, contrary to the common good. In this way, they exploit and deplete the "commons" (shared resource). In social loafing, one actor essentially assumes that someone else will do the work (produce the shared resource), thus they don't do anything (selfishly exploit the limited resources). As to whether it's propaganda…that's a matter of perspective and ultimately irrelevant.

Comment: @CodyGray What limited resource is the loafer exploiting?

Comment: The willingness of others to do the work, covering the spread for the loafer. Consider a game of tug-of-war: a social loafer isn't pulling as hard because they know that the other players on their team are pulling as hard as they can. Of course, the max force of (n - 1) people is less than the max force of n people. It may not matter to the outcome of that game, but it's still a limited resource. Perhaps you should ask a separate question about this? Unfortunately, there's no Sociology site on Stack Exchange, but perhaps [Psychology.SE] or [Economics.SE] would be suitable places to ask. @Kirt

Comment: @CodyGray I’m asking about a situation where f(n+1)<f(n), where f() is a measure of their total productivity.

Comment: @CodyGray If production is going down, as OP posits, I don't see how non-loafers are "covering the spread".  They are not having to work any harder because of the loafer.  They are already, as you say "pulling as hard as they can."  It sounds more like you are describing the "free rider problem", not the "tragedy of the commons."?

Comment: Based on that clarification, "social loafing" is not the correct term for what you have in mind. This is better described by Brooks's Law and/or the colloquial phrase cited by alphabet. Social loafing is where an individual in a group does less work because they are confident that others in the group will exert the effort necessary to complete the task anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I upvoted "too many cooks spoil the broth (or soup)" because I think it most closely matches the paradoxical effect of reduced efficiency from adding people to a task.

I also thought of the Bystander Effect, but as I understand it, that effect is usually brought up about others who just stand around and do nothing - rather than doing the same thing less efficiently. But I also see that it could be used to refer to reduced efficiency or to people who want to be helpful but end up being no help due to the effect of others around them.

"Passing the buck" or "diffusion of responsibility" don't sound fitting for this kind of concept, as far as I see it. Those terms are focused mainly on people who are deliberately avoiding certain work, as opposed to two people honestly trying to do a good job but suffering a drop in efficiency as a side-effect of being put on the same task.

Finally, there is the concept of the "mythical man month." This term is from a book on software development, so it is not useful to anyone who doesn't follow software or project management jargon. But it does capture the idea that adding people to a project tends to make that project even later. This concept, however, is about training and other overhead, not about one worker assuming another will do the same task, as is presented in the question's scenario.

> Therefore, assigning more programmers to a project running behind
> schedule will make it even later. This is because the time required
> for the new programmers to learn about the project and the increased
> communication overhead will consume an ever-increasing quantity of the
> calendar time available

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month#The_mythical_man-month

Comment: I don't think mythical man month applies here.  In that case, the extra worker is doing the same _general_ job as the other workers, i.e. "software developer", but the _specific_ job is different, i.e. "developing component X" where the other workers are "developing component A", "developing component B", and so on.  The extra cost comes from the increased communication required amongst all the developers.  But in this question, the two workers are doing _exactly the same job_, i.e. "checking all the widgets for defects", which does not require any intercommunication at all.

Comment: Thanks John, I agree. I also realized that "too many cooks" can also have a pejorative connotation (as in, each cook thinks they can do it best), but in general I think it best matches the question's request.

Comment: I would point out the term isn't *from* the book, the book is named *after* the term. It's a management term, where managers say a project will take X man-months or Y man-years of labor, making or eliding several false assumptions: (1) That humans are equally interchangeable, (B) that all the labor is parallelable (i.e. that one man's work isn't dependable on someone else finishing their work first), (C) that adding additional people doesn't have time-costs (i.e. training, as you pointed out), and (D) that adding additional people doesn't have communication/coordination/management time-costs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-hour

Comment: Thanks Jamin. I haven't read the whole book, so I appreciate the context that you added.

Answer (score 7):

This is also known as the law of **Diminishing Returns**

> For example, the law states that in a production process, adding workers might initially increase output. However, at a certain point the optimal output per worker will be reached. Beyond that point, each additional worker's efficiency will decrease because other factors of production remain unchanged, such the available resources.

Source: [TechTarget](https://www.techtarget.com/searchcustomerexperience/definition/law-of-diminishing-returns)

Comment: No, the law of diminishing returns is something different.  OP is asking about the case when two people together are less productive, or less accurate, or less desirable in some other way, than just one person.  The law of diminishing returns is when two people are less than twice as productive as one person.

Answer (score 5):

**Less than the sum of its parts**

The expression "greater than the sum of its parts" describes a situation where the combined efforts of two or more individuals exceed the sum of the capabilities of each individual. From [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/more-greater-than-the-sum-of-its-parts):

> If you say that something is more than the sum of its parts or greater
> than the sum of its parts, you mean that it is better than you would
> expect from the individual parts, because the way they combine adds a
> different quality.

This is often used with relation to pop groups - also from [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/more-greater-than-the-sum-of-its-parts):

> As individual members' solo careers have proved, each band was greater than the sum of its parts.

Accordingly, "**less than the sum of its parts**" is understood to describe a situation where the combined efforts of two or more individuals are less effective or of lower quality than you might expect, given the capabilities of each individual.

Revisiting the pop group example, this expression might be used where two or more successful / talented solo artists collaborate to produce a piece of music, which is judged to be underwhelming. (Naming no names...)

Answer (score 1):

“Asynergy” is actually a word with the meaning “ defective coordination between parts” (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/asynergy) but it has apparently been hijacked by the medical profession.  Still, its meaning would be clear, and its use outside medicine could be justified as metaphorical.  Similar remarks apply to “dyssynergy”.

If you prefer a less tainted word, then “anti-synergy” would be more than acceptable, not least because others have found it so - e.g.https://brill.com/abstract/book/9781848883574/BP000003.
xml

Answer (score 1):

The correct term is, TRAINING YOUR REPLACEMENT.
When a second person is added to do the job that you were able to handle on your own, the most common sense reason for why they are there is to replace you.
This will cause much dissatisfaction and resentment on the part of the initial worker, and tension between them both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the latter case *the buck doesn't stop with either one of them.* So the word/term is mutual **Buck passing.**

Also, *The Farlex Dictionary* gives this idiom for such a situation:

**pass the baton**

> To bestow one's responsibility or job upon someone else. [*An allusion to a relay race in which one runner literally hands a baton to the next runner.*]

*I have so much work to do now that my boss has retired and passed the baton to me.*

[pass the baton](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+the+baton)

Comment: "Passing the buck" has rather negative connotations; if someone does it, it's usually hurting someone else. "Passing the baton," on the other hand, is something expected to happen and has positive (you're replacing a tired runner with a fresh one), or at worst neutral, connotations.